# Python - home-made binary search function not working

Tags: python, search, binary

I've been learning python for about a week now, and I tried my hand at creating the binary search function:

```
def bin_srch(a, b, c, d):
    l_c = map(int, c.split(" "))
    l_d = map(int, d.split(" "))
    for n in l_d:
        if n <= l_c[a/2]:
            for j in l_c[0:(a/2)+1]:
                if j == n:
                    print l_c.index(j)+1,
                elif n not in l_c[0:(a/2)+1]:
                    print -1,

        elif n > l_c[a/2]:
            for j in l_c[a/2:a]:
                if j == n:
                    print l_c.index(j)+1,
                elif n not in l_c[a/2:a]:
                    print -1,
```

However, when I test the function with some input:

```
bin_srch(5,6,
"10 30 50 60 70",
"60 10 50 10 5")
```

yields `4 1 3 1 -1 -1 -1` instead of `4 1 3 1 -1`. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Please rename your parameters/variables to have more descriptive names

Comment: What is this function supposed to do exactly? Why are the results supposed to be `4 1 3 1 -1`?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't really understand what you're code is supposed to be doing, I'm pretty sure I know the problem:

```
for j in l_c[0:(a/2)+1]:
    if j == n:
        print l_c.index(j)+1,
    elif n not in l_c[0:(a/2)+1]:
        print -1,
```

So, for each value, if it's a match, print the match (and keep looking); otherwise, check it against of the same values you're already looping over (and are going to continue to loop over) and if it's not found, print `-1`. So, if something isn't a match, you're going to print `-1` multiple times.

What you probably want is:

```
for j in l_c[0:(a/2)+1]:
    if j == n:
        print l_c.index(j)+1,
        break
else:
    print -1,
```

At least this gives the desired output for this example. Why?

Well, the `break` means that as soon as you find a match, you stop going through the inner loop. The `else`—notice that it's attached to the `for`, not the `if`—runs if you finished the loop without ever `break`-ing. So, instead of checking for a match 3 times and printing `-1` each time, you just check for a match 3 times and print `-1` at the end, if you never found one.

(Actually, it looks like you could replace this whole loop with a `list.index` call, but I'll leave that up to you.)

Of course you have to make the same fix in the `elif` branch of your top-level `if`, because you have the same problem there.

Also, as a side note, if you write `if n <= l_c[a/2]:`, you don't need `elif n > l_c[a/2]:` Just use `else`; you already know that it's not true that `n <= l_c[a/2]` or you wouldn't have gotten here, therefore it must be true that `n < l_c[a/2]`, so you don't need to check it.